# iOS static library dead code stripping - configurable APNS

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, apple-push-notifications

We have a szenario were we provide a static library for iOS which contains code to register for Apples APNS (push notification service). The idea is that in order to activate push all the user of the library has to do is to derive his AppDelegate from one provided with the library.

```
@interface LibraryAppDelegate // code from the library 

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(nonnull NSData*)deviceToken

@end
```

---

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : LibraryAppDelegate 
@end
```

This works as expected as long as the user wants to use push. In case the user does **NOT** want to use push and simply does not derive from *LibraryAppDelegate* everything seems to work fine as well, at least at compile and link time.
The catch is that once the App is ready and gets archived and uploaded to the app store you will receive an email stating that the app has issues. More specific:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register
>   with the Apple Push Notification Service, ...

Since the user decided NOT to use APNS and the code inside the library never gets called my thinking was that during link time this code would be stripped, which obviously is not the case.

The following picture shows the current build settings for the library and the app.

[image]

So my question is, how can we provide code that gets stripped in case it is not used, referenced, needed? Thanks in advance.